# convert a binary search tree to a linkedlist in JAVA

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list, binary-search-tree

```
 public static BiNode linklist(BiNode root)
 {
    BiNode head = null, tail=null;
    convertBST(head, tail, root);
    return head;
 }



 public static void convertBST(BiNode head, BiNode tail, BiNode root)
 {
    BiNode leftTail = null, rightHead = null;
    if(root==null){
        head = null;
        tail = null;
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("root = "+root.key);
    convertBST(head, leftTail, root.node1);
    convertBST(rightHead, tail, root.node2);
    if(leftTail != null)
    {
        System.out.println("leftTail = "+leftTail.key);
        leftTail.node2 = root;
        root.node1 = leftTail;
    }else{
        head = root;
        System.out.println("head = "+ head.key+", root = "+root.key);
    }

       if(rightHead != null)
       {
        rightHead.node1 = root;
        root.node2 = rightHead;
       }else{
        tail = root;
        System.out.println("tail = "+ tail.key+", root = "+root.key);
       }
  }
```

above is my java code which is used to convert a BST to a double link list.

But I do not know why the head always change, which is supposed to point to the head of the link list and  not change.

I am glad great mind would help me debug this code! thanks!!!

Comment: Could you just post the code for `linklist()` and `convertBST()`? None of the other code appears to contribute to your BST to linked list logic, so it just clutters everything up.

It'll also help a bit if everything is indented neatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic key as to why the code is wrong is this line: `head = root;` and `tail = root;` in the method `public static void convertBST(BiNode head, BiNode tail, BiNode root)`

You are assuming that when you set a parameter to a new node it is propagated up the call stack (call by reference). Java does not do this. When you do `head = root;` you have only changed the local value of `head` not the value in the calling method.

Therefore in the method `public static BiNode linklist(BiNode root){`, `head` will always be `null` and the method will always return `null`.

Comment: I get it. But how to fix it? I know how to fix this kind problem in c/c++, but how to fix it in JAVA? thank you again

Comment: Either return the value(s) or pass in a mutable wrapper of the values